# Can't go into advanced mode in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I cannot find advanced mode in SSRS 2008 R2.  I need to freeze the top row in a tablix so it stays there when scrolling on a report.  Apparently I can do this in "advanced mode", but when I click the arrow to the right of the groups in the grouping pane, I do not have the advanced mode option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this screenshot:

[image]

I think you are clicking on the row groups arrow.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: You are welcome, It took minutes to me recently when I was trying to play with this feature too.